# Amazon MWS - Value missing for country of origin - _POST_FLAT_FILE_BOOKLOADER_DATA_

Tags: amazon-mws

I used to upload books to "amazon.fr" with the feed template "*POST_FLAT_FILE_BOOKLOADER_DATA*" using amazon MWS.
Since august,due to the new obligatory field "country of orign", i received the folowwing mistake :

original-record-number  sku error-code  error-type  error-message
0       90215   Error   100% of the products in your file did not process successfully.
1   49487   99010   Error   A value is missing from one or more required columns from this group: [country_of_origin = null].

However, the field is missing in the template accessible on the following page : https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_FR/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html

Please guide me how to fix the issue.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you found a solution ? I have the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Baro, yes problem sloved, you have to contact the amazon support which send you the correct template. The current template accessible on the page https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_FR/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html is not correct.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply Thomas! Yesterday I found the correct file, their guides are old and confusing, but in the help section (not the one for developers) I found the updated file. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Problem sloved, you have to contact the amazon support which send you the correct template. The current template accessible on the page docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_FR/feeds/… is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having problems with this like I was, the link to the actual templates is here https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/help/hub/reference/G1641?ref=efph_G1641_cont_200339940&locale=en_GB
scroll down to Category-Specific Templates and select the category you need